# Magnetic field in a wire with constant current

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

I assume I have a wire parellel to the $z$ axis and with radius $R$. A constant current $I$ flows through it in the $z$ direction. I want to know the magnetic field inside the wire at distance $r<R$.
In the figure, the pink dots represent the flow of electrons in the z direction for $r<R$. The red dots represent the the flow of electrons in the z direction for $r>R$. I added the green magnetic field $B_o$, so that one might be wrong.
The formula I came across is:
$$  B=\frac{\mu_{0} I r}{2 \pi R^2} = \frac{\mu_{0} I_{enc} }{2 \pi r}  \text{ for } r<R$$
Why does the magnetic field (blue in figure) at $r$ only depend on the magnetic field caused by the enclosed current $I_{enc}$ (the pink dots) ? 
Why isn't there an influence by the magnetic field caused by the remainder of the current [$ I-I_{enc}$] (red dots)? For example, from $r \angle 40$ radially towards $R \angle 40$ there is current flowing in the $z$ direction (3 consecutive red dots in figure) which at $r \angle 40$ causes a magnetic field (green $B_o$ in figure) that is opposite to the one caused by the enclosed current (blue in figure), or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship you propose **only** applies if the current has symmetry with respect to the axis of the wire.

Amperes law is that the line integral of the B-field around a closed loop equals the enclosed current times $\mu$.

$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} = \mu I$$

To get your relationship you need to assume that on any circular path around the axis, that (I) the B-field is parallel to the path and (II) is of constant magnitude. These conditions are satisfied for circular symmetry of the current distribution.

Effectively what happens is that the B -field due to the current in the annulus around the circle exactly cancels to zero inside the circle. But I stress again, this only happens when everything is nicely symmetric.

In your diagram, I count 7 dots in the outer part of the wire in the top left quadrant and 5 in the bottom right. Therefore the current distribution *does not* have circular symmetry, the B-field in the wire will not have circular symmetry and you cannot easily use Ampere's law to calculate it! I suspect this is either careless drawing, or done by someone who isn't (yet) completely understanding when and how you can apply Ampere's law. **So, assuming the drawing is accurate then you are not (completely) wrong.** Though of course one would have to integrate the contributions from all parts of the wire.

Comment: The figure doesn't show the current density correctly. It should have been a constant current density throughout the entire cross section. I don't know how I can mathematically show that the B-field caused by the current in the annulus ($r>R$) cancels to zero inside the circle $r<R$

Comment: Do you need to do that? If the current *is* cylindrically symmetric you don't, because Ampere's law tells you that this is what must happen. If you wish to do it out of curiosity then the route would be to do an integral over the annulus using the Biot-Savart law.

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I'll read more about Ampere's law, clearly there is something I don't understand. I will try to do it with Biot-Savart. Edit to my previous comment: .. I don't know how I can mathematically show that the B-field caused by the current in the annulus ($r<r_2<R$) cancels to zero inside the circle $0<r_1<r$.

Comment: A constant current density doesn't imply circular symmetry, right? Is circular symmetry only achieved when there is a continuous constant current density at each circle [at each circle with radius $r_i$  there is either flow of electrons at at each point of that circle with radius $r_i$ or there is no flow of electrons at each point of that circle with radius $r_i$ ;  and by $r_i$ I mean $0 \leq r_i \leq R , r_i \in \mathbb{R} $]? If so, can it really happen that the current density of a wire has circular symmetry or is it always an approximation?

Comment: On http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_symmetry is says :"Circular symmetry in mathematical physics applies to a 2-dimensional field which can be expressed as a function of distance from a central point only.This means that all points on each circle take the same value."

Comment: @M_E A uniform current density does have circular (cylindrical) symmetry so long as the wire also has a circular cross section. (A square cross-section wire would not). The same applies to any current density that depends only on distance from the centre of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic fields for the currents outside exactly cancel each other... That's just how the law of magnetism works.

Comment: How can they cancel each other at distance $r \angle 30$ for example? What cancels the opposite field at $r\angle 30$ caused by the current that is between $r \angle 30$ and  $R \angle 30$ flowing in $z$ direction?

Comment: First recognize there is symmetry about the central axis of the wire. Now imagine a thin shell of current at distance R. At any point inside you "see" bits of current on all sides - each of which gives rise to a magnetic field which has a magnitude and direction depending on the distance and angle. The vector sum of all these little elements of currents adds up to zero when there is no current inside the shell. So all the shells at distance greater than r in your situation might as well not be there. It's just how the math works.

Comment: Floris what you say only works for a symmetric current distribution. I'm sure you know that, but you have missed that the current distribution *isn't* symmetric and this appears to be the problem for the OP. So they are actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ampere's Law. That magnetic field that you calculated depends on $r$ and the enclosed current is $j*ds$ where $j$ is the current density and $ds$ is surface differential. So if you want to know the magnetic field outside of a wire you should take a $r>R$.